# Passing over an array in JS that contains objects that contain objects

Tags: javascript, arrayobject

I have an array of objects that contains children,
There will not always be children, sometimes there will be grandchildren
How can I go through it in JAVA SCRIPT and print it?

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "sara",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "dian"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "michael",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "dkny"
          },
          {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Anne"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Tommy"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "danken",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "biria"
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

I tried to go through the for loop on the children,
Only it does not pass on to the grandchildren and great-grandchildren

Comment: What kind of traversal? What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: The output will print the array
I prefer going through the loop

Comment: A page must be built according to the json information that comes from the "server".
The page structure is performed by JS when the information (DATA) that the function receives looks like this - (array above)
After working the function, the page will show that every child is inside the father,
And a grandson inside a grandfather.
I know how to display the creation of the HTML elements on the page
I just got into trouble going through the array

Comment: ... in what order should the data be printed? 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8?

Comment: The printing will be done in
Father: 1
       Son: 2
               3
            Grandson: 4
                             5


Father: 6
            Son: 7
                    Grandson: 8

Comment: The computer shows no profit.
But let him print in such a way that everyone is inside his father

Answer (score 1):

What you want is essentially an in-order traversal, like this:

```js
const data=[{"id":"1","name":"sara","children":[{"id":"2","name":"dian"},{"id":"3","name":"michael","children":[{"id":"4","name":"dkny"},{"id":"5","name":"Anne"}]}]},{"id":"6","name":"Tommy"},{"id":"7","name":"danken","children":[{"id":"8","name":"biria"}]}];

function inorder(data) {
    data.forEach((datum) => {
        console.log(datum.id);
        
        if (datum.children) inorder(datum.children);
    });
}

inorder(data);
```

or if you want the result as an array to be used later:

```js
const data=[{"id":"1","name":"sara","children":[{"id":"2","name":"dian"},{"id":"3","name":"michael","children":[{"id":"4","name":"dkny"},{"id":"5","name":"Anne"}]}]},{"id":"6","name":"Tommy"},{"id":"7","name":"danken","children":[{"id":"8","name":"biria"}]}];

function inorder(data, a = []) {
    data.forEach((datum) => {
        const copy = { ...datum };
        delete copy.children;
        a.push(copy);
        
        if (datum.children) inorder(datum.children, a);
    });
    
    return a;
}

console.log(inorder(data));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me
I did the experiment and they don't print inside each other
That means that the son will be printed inside the father
And the grandson inside the son
Can you help me why this is so?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
try this

```
const printData = (data) => {
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Father: ${data[i].name}`)
    if (data[i].children) {
        for (let j = 0; j < data[i].children.length; j++) {
            console.log(`Son: ${data[i].children[j].name} with father ${data[i].name}`)
            if (data[i].children[j].children) {
                for (let k = 0; k < data[i].children[j].children.length; k++) {
                    console.log(`Grandson: ${data[i].children[j].children[k].name} with father ${data[i].children[j].name} and grandfather ${data[i].name}`)
                }
            } else {
                console.log(`Son has no children`)
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log(`Father has no children`)
    }
 }

}


printData(data)
```

**Old Answer**
you can prepare your data using recursion

```
const data = [
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "sara",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "dian"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "michael",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "name": "dkny"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "name": "Anne"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Tommy"
},
{
    "id": "7",
    "name": "danken",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "biria"
        }
    ]
}
]

let preparedData = []

const prepareData = (data) => {
   for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       preparedData.push({id: data[i].id, name: data[i].name})
       if (data[i].children) {
        prepareData(data[i].children)
       }
   }

}

prepareData(data)

console.log(preparedData)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me
I did the experiment and they don't print inside each other
That means that the son will be printed inside the father
And the grandson inside the son
Can you help me why this is so?

Comment: can you explain more, i didn't understand what exactly should be the structure

Comment: The structure should be: Inside a large DIV the father will be printed, Inside it will be printed a DIV with the boys In other words, every son will be imprinted in the name of his father, every grandson within his father and within his grandfather I know the HTML structure thank you a lotttttt

Comment: please help me!!!  
I'm stuck and I don't know how to move forward,
I'm at a loss